# Late 80s or early 90s book ID: boy aboard land schooner

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for the title of a book that I believe I read in the late 80s or early 90s. The storyline was about a boy who was an employee/slave aboard a land schooner - A big wheeled vessel similar to a clipper with wheels. I thought it had the word 'heart' in the title. That's all I have - Thanks.

Comment: What elements make it sci-fi or fantasy ?

Comment: Mick Farren's "Phaid" series (#1 Phaid the Gambler, 1981) has land schooners (land crawlers). Some of the story takes place on them with minor characters (I recall interaction with a slave/prostitute girl), but the plot doesn't centre around them.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a short story from Terry Dowling's Tom Rynoseros cycle.  Possibly "No Hearts to Be Broken".  The Tom Rynoseros stories featured land-going ships that crossed the Australian deserts under kite.